# How does one add HTML code in a JS function?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following js to replace text in a class called .relatedactivities with another text. In the example below the text is Related Activities.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".relatedactivities").text('Related Activities');
})
</script>
```

How can I replace the text "Related Activities" with the HTML code below instead?

```
<h1 class="GreenLrg" align="center">Related Activities</h1>
<div align="center"> <a href="/activities/kauai/ziplineadventures/koloa-zipline.htm">
<div class="CatBox"><img src="/Portals/0/1koloa-zipline-tour-2.jpg" height="174" width="231"><span>Koloa Zipline Tour</span></div>
</a> <a href="/activities/kauai/ziplineadventures/zip-n-dip-expedition.htm">       
<div class="CatBox"><img src="/Portals/0/2zip-n-dip-2.jpg" height="174" width="231"><span>Zip N' Dip Expedition</span></div>
</a> <a href="/activities/kauai/ziplineadventures/kipu-falls-safari.htm">
<div class="CatBox"><img src="/Portals/0/3kipu-zipline-safari-2.jpg" height="174" width="231"><span>Kipu Zipline Safari</span></div>
<p></p>
</a></div><a href="/activities/kauai/ziplineadventures/kipu-falls-safari.htm">
```

Comment: Have you tried a div with innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not suggest you hard code HTML in your JavaScript, as it will become extremely difficult to maintain in the long run.

In a perfect world, you can call a backend service via AJAX which would return HTML, or you could use a framework or library like AngularJS or React.JS.

Now, to answer you question, simply change `.text()` for `.html('<html here/>')`.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$(".relatedactivities").html('<h1 class="GreenLrg" align="center">Related Activities</h1>...');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: html() like

```
 $(".relatedactivities").html('your code html');
```

This method uses the browser's innerHTML property. Some browsers may not return HTML that exactly replicates the HTML source in an original document. For example, Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

For more about that, check http://api.jquery.com/html/